# Use Dependency Injection to pass token acquisition from startup.cs to HomeController.cs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a DI for the following code from the Startup.cs file. But being new to .net I'm having a tough time figuring out a solution.

```
var tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
     .GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>() as ITokenAcquisition;

var graphClient = GraphServiceClientFactory
    .GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(async () =>
    {
        return await tokenAcquisition
            .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(GraphConstants.Scopes);
    }
);
```

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.InMemory;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace AD_Lookup
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            // Add Microsoft Identity Platform sign-in
            services.AddSignIn(options =>
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);

                options.Prompt = "select_account";

                var authCodeHandler = options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived;
                options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context => {
                    // Invoke the original handler first
                    // This allows the Microsoft.Identity.Web library to
                    // add the user to its token cache
                    await authCodeHandler(context);

                    var tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                        .GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>() as ITokenAcquisition;

                    var graphClient = GraphServiceClientFactory
                        .GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(async () =>
                        {
                            return await tokenAcquisition
                                .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(GraphConstants.Scopes);
                        }
                    );

                    // Get user information from Graph
                    var user = await graphClient.Users["carvalhostephen20@hotmail.com"]
                        .Request()
                        .GetAsync();

                    context.Principal.AddUserGraphInfo(user);

                };


                options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context => {
                    var error = WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Exception.Message);
                    context.Response
                        .Redirect($"/Home/ErrorWithMessage?message=Authentication+error&debug={error}");
                    context.HandleResponse();

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                };

                options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = context => {
                    if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException)
                    {
                        var error = WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Failure.Message);
                        context.Response
                            .Redirect($"/Home/ErrorWithMessage?message=Sign+in+error&debug={error}");
                        context.HandleResponse();
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                };
            }, options =>
            {
                Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
            });

            

            // Add ability to call web API (Graph)
            // and get access tokens
            services.AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi(Configuration,
                GraphConstants.Scopes)
                // Use in-memory token cache
                // See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/token-cache-serialization
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            // Require authentication
            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            // Add the Microsoft Identity UI pages for signin/out
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            //if (env.IsDevelopment())
            //{
            //    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            //    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            //    app.UseHsts();
            //}
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Homecontroller.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using AD_Lookup.Models;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenCacheProviders.InMemory;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace AD_Lookup.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        }


        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        
        public IActionResult UserSearch()
        {
            //string searchText = model.SearchBoxText;
            //ViewData["searchData"] = searchText;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SearchBox(UserSearchModel model)
        {
            string searchText = model.SearchBoxText;
            ViewData["searchData"] = searchText;

            var tokenAcquisition = this.HttpContext.RequestServices
                    .GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>() as ITokenAcquisition;

            var graphClient = GraphServiceClientFactory
                    .GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(async () =>
                    {
                        var accessToken =
 await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(GraphConstants.Scopes, "2b51e32f-e865-48ef-b075-0a456dc76468");
                        return accessToken;
                        //    .GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(GraphConstants.Scopes, "2b51e32f-e865-48ef-b075-0a456dc76468");
                    }
                );
            var user = await graphClient.Users[searchText]
                    .Request()
                    .GetAsync();

            return View();
            //return Content($"Hello {model.SearchBoxText}");
        }

        public IActionResult GroupSearch()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of copying the same code within my controller, I want to pass the values of tokenacquisition using DI.

Using the graph API I'm trying to print user information based on the email id inputted in a text box.
The graphAPI provides the following code snippet that im trying to implement.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var user = await graphClient.Users["carvalhostephen20@hotmail.com"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

This can be found at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
Search for the sample query users by email. This is the functionality that i'm trying to implement.

Having the Startup.cs code copied into the controller causes solution to fail and return the following error page:
[image: ErrorPage1]

[image: ErrorPage2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, i get you question wrong first time. So basicly you registrate your `ITokenAcquisition` when call `services.AddWebAppCallsProtectedWebApi()`. Try to modify your `Homecontroller`. Remove this line:

```
var tokenAcquisition = this.HttpContext.RequestServices
                .GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>() as ITokenAcquisition;
```

And use this instance instead: `_tokenAcquisition`

Comment: @lobster, transient objects are always new. New objects are created every time they are requested (asked for an instance through DI). If we want to use it at a web request level, it is supposed to be Scoped lifetime (varies for every new request). More about it here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options

Comment: @SaiGummaluri Thanks for observation, but i mean request to service container.

Comment: This needs to be added within the startup.cs file right?

Instead of the following line: 

`var tokenAcquisition = context.HttpContext.RequestServices
                        .GetRequiredService<ITokenAcquisition>() as ITokenAcquisition;`
@lobstar

Comment: Also what does the word sp mean in the parameter section? @lobstar

Comment: @stephencarvalho You need to add this code fragment into startup.cs, but not instead. `sp` is an instance of `IServiceProvider` you can use it to get another dependencies from service container

Comment: @lobstar I'm still getting the same error. How do I use it within my homecontroller to consume the graph api code?

`GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var user = await graphClient.Users["carvalhostephen20@hotmail.com"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();`

Comment: @stephencarvalho I'm change my answer, you can check this out

Answer (score 0):

I faced "No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent" a few times too.

In my case every time this occured the solution was cleaning the complete browser history (including cookies). I didn't investigate the exact cause because this solution was good enough for me, but it seems to be caused by the browser caching some token that needs to be refreshed after having changed something to the tokenacquisitiong code.